# How can I use Enter to call event handler?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `textBox` and search `button`, I would ask about how can I make the user can click Enter to start searching without need to go and click the search `button`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Form has a property called "AcceptButton" that identifies a button that should be associated to the "Enter" keypress.  Its considered the "default action" for the form.

More info here:

[Windows Form - AcceptButton property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

This would be best practice

```
private void txtSearch_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AcceptButton = btnSearch;
}

private void txtSearch_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AcceptButton = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use something other than Enter/Return, you could also try:

```
private void EnterKeyAction()
{
   // Search...
}

private void btnEnter_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
          EnterKeyAction();    
}

private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     EnterKeyAction();
}
```