# .net trigger a button with enter key

Tags: .net, button, c++-cli

In .net, I have a tabpage on a tabcontrol. I added a button to the tabpage and I want that enter key trigger the button.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can set the button to be the default - there's a property that's exposed in Visual Studio - which will be the action taken when enter is pressed.

Comment: there is a property as IsDefault, but when I set the IsDefault property to true, it gives an error:
'System::Windows::Forms::ButtonBase::IsDefault::set' :candidate function not accessible

Comment: This could help you:
[How can I use Enter to call event handler?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954042/how-can-i-use-enter-to-call-event-handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the ProcessCmdKey() method was designed to do.  Override it like this:

```
protected:
    virtual bool ProcessCmdKey(Message %msg, Keys keyData) override {
        if (keyData == Keys::Enter) {
            button1->PerformClick();
            return true;
        }
        return __super::ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData);
    }
```

Form::AcceptButton is good for dialogs.

Comment: Why it doesn't work for me? I set the breakpoint but it never passed there. And I used a key event handler to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Form.KeyPreview = true` and then

```
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            button1_Click(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

or (as @ChrisF told you)
you can set `Form.AcceptButton = button1` and the job is done

Comment: But it is not only one button; I added a tabcontrol on a form. And lets say 3 tabpage, and a button for all of them. A button on tabpage one, B button on tabpage tree... When the second tabpage is open, the enter key must trigger the B button.

Comment: @user983924: with my first solution, procedure is raised every time you press a key everywhere in your form; so you catch ENTER button and, watching tab control SelectedIndex, run button click you want!

Comment: I wrote it but it did not handle "enter", it handle other keys like shift or 's' char. When I press enter, the program does nothing.

Comment: Maybe you're "trapping" ENTER somewhere else? Did you try to debug?

Comment: I guess you are right, the form selected one of it's controls and use the 'enter' key for it. I think it is related about tab index. Have any idea?